# Nonabelian group of order $p^4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $P$ be a nonabelian group of order $p^4$, where $p$ is a prime, and let $A$ be a subgroup of $P$ maximal with the property of being normal and abelian. Prove that $A$ is of order $p^3$.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it possible to have $H$ (of order $2^3=8$), the group of units of the quaternions, which is a subgroup of $H\times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$? Both these groups aren't abelian.

Comment: @Ragnar How is it relevant? $A$ was required to *be* abelian. It was not claimed that other subgroups couldn't be non-abelian.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right, there may be other subgroups that are abelian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is abelian and normal, there is an morphism $\rho : P/A \rightarrow {\rm Aut}(A)$ given by
$$\rho(\overline{\sigma})a:= \sigma a \sigma^{-1},$$
for all $\sigma \in P$ and $a \in A$.

If $A$ has order $\leq p^2$, then $\rho$ has a kernel. If $\overline{\sigma}_0 \in P$ is in the kernel, then the subgroup generated by $\sigma_0$ and $A$ is normal abelian (I let you fill in the details).